# Any idea how to implement a Transaction middleware that can be used by all the routes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the code I have.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const session = await mongoose.startSession();

session.startTransaction();

export default async function transactionMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    try {
        await session.withTransaction(async () => {
            await next();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'Something went wrong.'});
    }
    await session.commitTransaction();
    session.endSession();
};
```

[And this is how I am using in App.js file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhgS0.png)

My issue is that when i import this middleware, it doesn't compile. Im expecting to compile.

```
import transactionMiddleware  from './src/middlewares/transactionMiddleware.js';
```

[It crashes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY77U.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to create reusable code to handle your transactions you should probably use a wrapper function.

Pass it a function with the code to be executed in transaction as parameter:

```
const transactionWrapper = (callback) => {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    try {
        await session.withTransaction(async () => {
            await callback();
        });
        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();
    } catch (err) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
transactionWrapper(async () => {
    await dbOperationOne();
    await dbOperationTwo();
})
```